# Typescript infer the type of inner function in higher order function

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type SuperType<T = any> = {
    entities?: {
        [key: string]: T
    };
}

class Test<T> {
    value: T;

    constructor(v: T) {
      this.value = v;
    }

    update(cb: (v: T) => T) {
      this.value = cb(this.value);
    }
}

interface H extends SuperType<{ prop: number }> {}

const instance = new Test<H>({});
```

I want to create a higher-order function that updates the value:

```
function updateSomething<
    T extends SuperType,
    E = T extends SuperType<infer I> ? I : never>(arg: E) {
    return function (value: T) {
       return value;
    }
}
```

How can I infer the generic type in the higher-order function?

```
instance.update(updateSomething(placeholder))
```

So here `placeholder` should be typed as `{ prop: number }`

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to accomplish with `E` and also maybe more examples of what the return value of `updateProp` would look like? Would it update just name or just id depending on the name of the prop? Maybe increment the `id` and and prepend "Mr" to `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how `SuperType` is involved at all, since `H` is not assignable to `SuperType`.  I'm going to ignore `SuperType` for now and you can tell me if your question needs to be altered to make use of it.

---

My inclination for typing `updateProp()` would be the following:

```
function updateProp<K extends PropertyKey>(prop: K) {
    return function <T extends Record<K, any>>(value: T) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here I'm saying that `K` is allowed to be any keylike thing, and then the returned function will accept any value with `K` as a key and return the same type of thing.  This has the intended effect when used with `instance.update()`:

```
instance.update(updateProp('name')); // okay
instance.update(updateProp('id')); // okay
instance.update(updateProp('notExists')); // error, as desired
```

Does that work for you?  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuAeWA+aBvAsAKGkOgDcwQBXeALjgG598jpgB7AO2QCdzgkXOAFMRqwAlNkZMiSABYBLCADpSFeNAC8JegSIBfBjsLkADgBMwSeAOAAjGkJHj1mMRMNTZC5WUobmNgU8lFUpRbSZ9PEj8JABPYzUACT8saDYwAFtqaC45NgBzABpoOVMaNnIMm3hOaF1tfFYOJBLmsDZgNU02eAB3OERURPQBVPSsmgBySeLSmgBGOrDGfAAzcg6kOXZoE3NLAAVOFmMUAGloeAAPSzZTGCOTmriz+FiR42PjGjPxXHdOPAkOROGxoOtNtswWhLjd4HcYAAleCsTimc7FdrvEYhbKuf5SIiA4Ggkg+eDhPT4aJ4PLIdqdRR7CxWZmHL4CSbjeCTUTLWltDrwJlmFkCNnwR7GTmlXn8ulIBnCiXi0Xsk6ctgsJAAUSuCiQEDltGgAHpTZdOMdOEA)

---

### UPDATE

For your modified example I've changed the typing but kept the same basic idea: you need `updateProp()` to be generic in the type of its argument, and then calculate the other types from it:

```
function updateProp<E>(prop: E) {
    return function <T extends SuperType<E>>(value: T) {
        return value;
    }
}
instance.update(updateProp({ prop: 123 })); // okay
instance.update(updateProp({ prop: "" })); // error
instance.update(updateProp({ prop: 123, unexpectedProp: 456 })); // error
```

Hope that helps again; good luck.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It was the simplest use case I could write. I've updated the question.

Comment: updated my answer to fit your new example code; please review.